# URL rewirte from HTTP to HTTPS is not working

Tags: http, https, iis-8

I'm trying to create a rewrite rule for IIS 8, to redirect ALL non-secure requests to HTTPS equivalent.

This is what I've come to:

```
  <rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="HttpToHttps" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(http://)?([^/]+)(/.*)?" ignoreCase="true" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{PATH_INFO}?{QUERY_STRING}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

The problem is, sometimes it stops working. It's not like not working always, or working always. Sometimes it works like a charm, and sometimes it doesn't work.

What might be the problem? I have no idea and no clue on how to debug this.